# Complexity of scanning a bounded length string. O(n) or O(1)?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, analysis

Suppose we have a string of **unique ASCII characters**, which means that its length will never exceed 128 characters.

If I am to scan this string, where *scanning* means performing a *constant-time* operation on every character, does this scan counts as O(n), or O(1)?

Where **n** is the actual length of the string.

Comment: There is no `n` in `128`, so it cannot be `O(n)`.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia n is the actual string length!

Comment: Yes, but `n <= 128`, so in this case `O(n) <= O(128) = O(1)`. In other words, the scanning algorithm is `O(n)` in the general case, but given that you will apply it when `n <= 128`, your particular usage of the algorithm is `O(1)`.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia Your reasoning is good, but in practice, we always know that the string length will never exceed the Ram capacity, which is constant as well! However, we concider it to be linear time!

Comment: Right. But the amount of memory is theoretically unbounded, while in your case there is a "hard" upper bound of 128.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The answer

When asking for the time or space complexity of an algorithm in terms of `n`, you need to define what `n` is.

A linear scan of an array of `n` characters has, as you know, a time complexity of `O(n)`. Since you are applying this same algorithm to your array of <= 128 characters, you can definitely be correct in saying that you are applying an `O(n)` algorithm to your array.

However, if you define the algorithm as "scanning through a character array of max 128 characters", then your algorithm will indeed have a time complexity of `O(1)` because its number of operations is upper-bounded by a constant.

So to answer your question: It is a matter of perspective. How do you define your algorithm?

- "A generalized scan of an array of length `n`"? Then it's `O(n)`, where `n` in your particular application just so happens to never exceed 128 (good for you).
- "A scan of 128 or fewer characters"? Then it's `O(1)`, because its time is upper-bounded by a constant.

## Philosophizing a little further

Now, even if you were to extend the length of your array to fill up all your RAM, however large, it is still a finite integer and therefore you would, mathematically, be completely correct in claiming that it will run in `O(1)` time. *However!* How relevant is it to define an algorithm which scans through an array which fits in your RAM? We have just severely diminished the usefulness of our algorithm, because if, say, I have more RAM than you then your algorithm will not serve my needs.

This is why we use a parameter, `n`, to denote some metric (here the length of the array). This *allows* us to define a scanning algorithm which works for inputs of ANY(!) size. As you know, this algorithm is at best `O(n)`, which may not sound as nice as `O(1)`, but it is now a general algorithm which can be used for any input size as opposed to the one where we included the input limit as part of the algorithm itself.

Answer (score 0):

On one hand it is O(n) because the complexity of the program depends on some variable n that can change widthin a range of [0, 128].

On the other hand you would have O(1) if the program makes always the same amount of operations. That is not the case because if it's length es bigger it will require more work.

Although considering that the worst case scenario being O(128) thus making it O(1)